# python coverage - specify the working directory

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, code-coverage

I have a django application called edison with multiple django-apps in it. I run tests on them using coverage:

```
coverage run --source='.' edison/manage.py test application_one
coverage run --source='.' edison/manage.py test application_two
...
```

My repo structure is:

```
-- edison [the repo name]
    -- edison [a django application]
    -- schuedled_jobs
    -- internal_packages
```

In my tests files I import stuff from `internal_packages` directory and when I run the coverage commands i get the error
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'internal_packages'`.
My question is: how do I change the working directory of coverage to be the root directory - so it will recognise all modules?

Comment: You can probably get away with simply adding internal_packages to the system path. `sys.path.append('relative/path/to/internal_packages/from/edison_app_folder')`. Do this before you import it.

Comment: I ended up with `sys.path.append(os.getcwd())` which solved my issue. But i was hoping to solve it in the command-line level and not change my python code for it

Answer (score 0):

This will probably fix your problem. It just adds the repo directory to the system path, so python can find what you are requesting.

```
import sys, os

rel = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '../')
if not rel in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(rel)

from internal_packages import some_module
```

This gives a cleaner path than the relative version in the above example

```
rel = '/'.join(os.getcwd().split('/')[0:-1])
```

I believe this can also be solved by creating a proper `__init__.py` file for your modules.